# Is was or were Correct Verb

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement

After the phrase, "a supply of school supplies and snacks", would I use was sent or were sent for the verb in the sentence?

Comment: Note that although grammatically legal (and a good study case for learning), the repetition of "supply" is awkward and would be avoided in ordinary speaking/writing.  People would reword it, perhaps to: _"a shipment of school supplies and snacks was sent"_ or _"shipments of school supplies and snacks were sent"_

Answer (score 1):

You would use "was sent" because "supply," not "supplies," is the subject. Ignore the prepositional phrase.